# Удалённая сборка web-серверов на golang

Tags: golang, развертывание

Какие решения можете посоветовать для удобной сборки проектов на Go на удаленном сервере?
В идеале была бы хороша следующая схема: деплой изменений сорцов на сервер по ФТП или стянуть последнюю версию из svn -> сборка -> рестарт на новую версию. Если это ещё всё можно напрямую из IDE делать, а не дёргать сервер каждый раз по ssh, то совсем отлично.

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я понял, вы хотите перезапускать программу при изменении ваших файлов. Странно, но на go я такого нашел и накатал свой велосипед https://github.com/unclepotap/gosupervisor, умеет смотреть изменения в директориях/поддиректориях, убивает текущий процесс и запускает новый через go run. Что касается поддержки ssh, я думаю ее не сложно прикрутить.

Answer (score 0):

Пардон, а чем вас не устраивает:

```
go build projectName.go
pkill projectName
./projectName
```

PS Какой IDE пользуетесь, если не секрет?

Кстати, я перезапуск прямо из браузера делаю.

Примерно такой код:

```
if reader.RequestURI == "/restart-SECRET_KEY" {
    // Убиваем процессы модели
    cmd := exec.Command("pkill")
    cmd.Args = append(cmd.Args, "model")
    cmd.Start()
    // Убиваем сборщик почты
    cmd = exec.Command("pkill")
    cmd.Args = append(cmd.Args, "mailChecker")
    cmd.Start()
    // Стартуем новый контроллер
    cmd = exec.Command(config.Get("main_path")+"/controller")
    cmd.Args = append(cmd.Args, "-d="+config.Get("main_path"))
    cmd.Start()
    // алес
    os.Exit(0)
}
```

И все, достаточно пройти по ссылке и программа перезапускает сама себя.
Добавьте сюда еще пересборку проекта и ваш вопрос решен :)

Comment: >Пардон, а чем вас не устраивает:
Не у страивает тем, что если есть, например, открытые соединения по WebSockets, то они упадут, или если какой-то процесс или запрос обрабатывается в это время, то он не отработается правильно полностью. Если я ошибаюсь, объясните, пожалуйста, почему.

>PS Какой IDE пользуетесь, если не секрет?
Плагин mtoader'а для Intellij IDEA.

>Кстати, я перезапуск прямо из браузера делаю.
Тоже вариант, но мне почему-то не импонирует. Может дать привычки. Для меня в идеале, если бы это можно было делать с коммандной строки, например: $ ./mysiteapp -graceful_restart

Comment: > Кстати, я перезапуск прямо из браузера делаю.

Тоже вариант, но мне почему-то не импонирует. Может дань привычки, а может паранойя, что не безопасно) Для меня в идеале, если бы это можно было делать с командной строки, например: $ ./mysiteapp -graceful_restart

Comment: Ау? Есть кто?

Answer (score 0):

[Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano)?

Comment: Посмотрел по ссылке, довольно интересно, но в DEPENDENCIES указано Ruby. Устанавливать его только для этой задачи в принципе не проблема, но может быть есть варианты проще?
В любом случае - спасибо за пищу для размышлений.

Comment: capistrano -- стандратный инструмент для задач такого рода (называется deployment)

Answer (score 0):

Вы упомянули про открытые соединения?
Поможет?
http://habrahabr.ru/post/202584/